# Coercivity of this function.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, coercive

Let the following hold:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and  $F:H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and convex with $$\lim_{\|x\| \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|F(x)|}{\|x\|} =\infty.$$

How do I show that $F$ is coercive, i.e. that $F(x) \rightarrow +\infty$ for $\|x\| \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: This condition is known as supercoercivity. The proof is based on the fact that $F(x)$ cannot be bounded as $\|x\|\to\infty$. By the way, you should change $F(x)\to\infty$ to $|F(x)|\to\infty$